Power Query Import For Power BI with group by on SelectRows
An update: I was trying to do this with Power Query import into Power bi. I didn't realize how easy it would have been to do with DAX. Thanks for the answers that were specific to Power Query Like I originally specified.
I am trying to add a column to an import in power query to import to power bi that shows the next time an order happens, to let me see if a re-order was made / known at that point in time.
Sample data
Orders Table



Item
OrderDate




Red
1/1/2024


Blue
1/1/2024


Yellow
1/1/2024


Red
2/1/2024


Yellow
2/1/2024


Red
3/1/2024


Yellow
3/1/2024



The result table would show the next date an order happens, for each order, with the join being on the "Item" and the date being the first record greater than the current row date.
Result



Result






Item
OrderDate
Next Order Date


Red
1/1/2024
2/1/2024


Blue
1/1/2024
null


Yellow
1/1/2024
2/1/2024


Red
2/1/2024
3/1/2024


Yellow
2/1/2024
3/1/2024


Red
3/1/2024
null


Yellow
3/1/2024
null



I have accomplished this via merged queries using the transform button and then conditional columns to narrow down the result (creating a table with a full outer join), but given the size of the dataset this join creates far too many rows in the import that are then just removed from the dataset.
I would like to use a column formula for selectrows, which I think would involve table.selectrows (table.group), but also needs to join on the item and the next order date being greater than the order data in each row.
I see lots of information on selectrows, or group by, but not on an efficent way to pass this back to the mysql database.
if I were writing the mysql statement it would be
select
a.item
,a.orderdate
,min(nextorder.orderdate) as NextOrderDate
from orders a

left join orders as NextOrder on
a.item=NextOrder.item
and
NextOrder.orderdate>a.orderdate

group by 
a.item
,a.orderdate`


In powerquery you could try
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type), //to preserve sort order; not necessary
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Index", {"Item"}, {{"data", each 
    let zz=_,
    shiftedList = List.RemoveFirstN(Table.Column(zz,"OrderDate"),1)
    in Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(zz) & {shiftedList},Table.ColumnNames(zz) & {"Previous Date"}) , type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"OrderDate", "Index", "Previous Date"}, {"OrderDate", "Index", "Previous Date"}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded data",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}), //to preserve sort order; not necessary
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"}) //to preserve sort order; not necessary
in #"Removed Columns" //to preserve sort order; not necessary



You may find the following PQ code executes more rapidly:
let

//Replace next line with your actual data source
    Source = Table,
    
    next = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Next Order Date", 
        (r)=>Table.SelectRows(Source, each 
                    [Item]=r[Item] 
                    and [OrderDate]>r[OrderDate])[OrderDate]{0}?, 
                    type nullable date)
in
    next



Thank you horseyride. i was able to make your solution work.
As i continued googling, I also came across the "earlier" DAX function, which allows me to add a column easily. It is not done in the import like I asked, but does what i wanted by keeping the amount of data imported to the original single table set.
EARLIER(, )
the formula I used is this:
NextOrderDate = 
  CALCULATE(
      MIN(Orders[OrderDate]),
      FILTER(
          Orders,
          Orders[Item] = EARLIER(Orders[Item]) && 
          Orders[OrderDate] > EARLIER(Orders[OrderDate])
      )
   )


DAX measure is usually an elegant way to address such questions,
Next = 
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    OFFSET( 1, ORDERBY( Orders[OrderDate] ), PARTITIONBY( Orders[Item] ) ),
    Orders[OrderDate]
)

enter image description here
